# JSON file not working once published to azure but ok on local

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, azure

After much googling, trail and error, and frustration, this one has me stumped.

I have an MVC application published on Azure. I have a controller that queries the database and returns Json file to use as events in Fullcalendar as so:

```
        public JsonResult Events()
        {

            var ci = from c in db.CalendarItems
                     select c;

            var rows = new List<dynamic>();

            foreach(var item in ci)
            {
                if (item.ClassTime.HasValue)
                    rows.Add(new { ID = item.Id, title = item.title, start = item.start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + item.start.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"), end = item.end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + item.end.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")});
            }

            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Very simple... On my local, this generates a perfectly good file that looks like this:

```
[{"ID":1,"title":"Event1","start":"2015-08-04T19:00:00","end":"2015-08-04T08:00:00"},{"ID":2,"title":"Event2","start":"2015-08-06T19:00:00","end":"2015-08-06T08:00:00"},{"ID":3,"title":"Event3","start":"2015-08-14T19:00:00","end":"2015-08-14T08:00:00"}]
```

However, on the published azure site I get an error code 500.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Adding this to web.config:

   ```
   <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
   ```
2. Adding httpErrors existingResponse = "PassThrough" to system.webServier in my web.config.
3. Lot's of tweeking of the web.config file
4. Deleting the entire application and recreating it in azure
5. I set customerrors mode=off and I received this error: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." Just to be sure I double checked my connection string and MARS is active. Maybe the loop is the issue?

Comment: Does your mvc application has other action ? Does it return response ?

Comment: At least on a Azure web app (I don't know about IIS on a VM), you should not have to worry about setting the json mime type in the web config.  Can you see the exception in the eventlog or have you tried turning custom errors off so it will display the exception?  Perhaps just manually construct a fake event in the controller to take the db out of the equation for testing.

Comment: 500 is internal Server error. Have you tried to and exception handling to your Action. And in case of an exception you could return the message in the json for debugging purposes. Ort you could turn on error logging on the azure site

Comment: Just an info of 500 Server wont help much, try setting customerrors mode=Off in system.webserver and see what is exactly causing the error

Comment: @dotnetstep yes all of the other actions work fine.

Comment: Now it seems there are two issue. 1. Your database call in that event is getting failed. 2. Your data on Azure server is different from local and it might possible that it contains more data and your application httpruntime not configure to handle that response size.

Comment: @AbhishekSiddhu I set customerrors mode=off and that was definitely helpful. Updated the post above with the results. perhaps it's an issue with the loop?

Comment: @jakeh Few things 1) Is it ASP.NET 4.5+ MVC 5 or ASP.NET 5 MVC 6? 2) Where do you define the connection strings? 3) Might be a silly question but are you sure connection strings are different on local and Azure since you cant use LocalDB on Azure. 4) Most importantly make sure custom errors is off only for staging sites, Remove that line on production code

Comment: There is a problem with the Json Parser on the server side. Please change your ID to a String instead of Int. Specifically, use `rows.Add(new { ID = item.Id.ToString() ...`. And, the output Json should looks like `"ID":"1"`. And, try again to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue and how to resolve. Working with the azure support desk, I found that the azure **web** app architecture didn't support the json events to fullcalendar. I converted this application to a **cloud** app by downloading the Azure SDK and following the procedures here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service/

Now that the app is running on a VM, everything works fine. I didn't have to change any coding in the above example.